# Match start-of-search position in elisp regexp

Tags: regex, elisp

I am doing some parsing in elisp, and I have a string that I have partially consumed (let's assume its value is `"foobar123"`). Suppose that I've consumed the `"foobar"` (so I know that I need to start parsing from char 6) and am expecting to consume a `2`.

I've tried the following, and none of them do what I want.

```
(string-match "2" "foobar123" 6) ; Matches the `2` at character 7.
(string-match "^2" "foobar23" 6) ; Not at the beginning of line.
(string-match "\\`2" "foobar23" 6) ; Not at the beginning of string.
```

I have had success pulling out a substring and matching against that (i.e., `(string-match "^2" (substring "foobar23" 6))`), but this seems wasteful. It feel like I want a special character that means "match at start of search only", but I can't find one. Is there a better way?

Comment: There is no such regexp syntax that I'm aware of. An alternative solution might be to insert the string into a buffer, move the point as you consume the string and use the `\=` construct to match the point.

Comment: Phrase it as a definitive answer and I'll accept that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no such regexp syntax that I'm aware of.

An alternative solution is to insert the string into a buffer, move the point as you consume the string and use the `\=` construct to match the point.

Comment: I checked the latest elisp manual on gnu.org, you appear to be correct.

Comment: @JackKelly, I just realized that if you place the text in a buffer, it's more natural to use `(looking-at "...")` rather than something like `(re-search-forward "\\=...")`.

Comment: Thank you. I'll be sticking with strings for now because the parsing I'm doing is very small (ed addresses), but that's good to know.